Understanding conditional expectation regarding a $\sigma$ algebra better.
I am trying to get a better understanding on conditional expectation w.r.t $\sigma$-algebras.
First here are some definitions I know:
Definition 1:
Let $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(A_1,A_2,...)$ where $A_1,A_2,...$ is a countable partition of $\Omega$. We define $E(X|\mathcal{G}):=\sum_i 1_{A_i}E(X|A_i)$.
Definition 2:
Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.
We denote the sigma algebra generated by $X$ as $\sigma(X):=\{X^{-1}(B):B \in \mathcal{B}\}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel sigma algebra.
Definition 3:
Let $X$ be a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ s.t $E|X| < \infty$. Suppose $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a sub sigma algebra. Then we say a random variable $Z$ is the conditioned expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$, denoted $Z=E(X|\mathcal{G})$, if $Z$ is $\mathcal{G} $measurable and for all $G \in \mathcal{G}:
E(Z 1_G)=E(X 1_G)$.
My main question is: Why do we condition on a $\sigma$ algebra?
After all, in the begining we condition on events, later we condition on random variables.
As far as I understood, $E(X|Y)$ is a function dependent on the random variable $Y$,call it $h(Y):=E(X|Y)$. We can calculate the specific value of $E(X|Y)$ for $Y=y$, $E(X|Y=y)$.
Why do we condition of $\sigma$-algebras?
Thinking about it I got:
Given a random variable $Y$, the sigma algebra generated by $Y$ is the smallest $\sigma$ algebra containing the preimages of $Y$. Thus the $\sigma$ algebra is a collection of all events we can condition on. This would mean that $E(X|\sigma(Y))$ is a function of $\sigma(Y) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
This looks like a construction to be able to view conditioning on events, but not as a specific number i.e. for an event $A$ and r.v. $X$, $E(X|A)$, but to have the conditional expectation as a function of events.
Those were my thoghts about it. Is my interpretation correct? Is there something I miss?
